# Create a new 100 % total column for every group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, percentage

I want to create a new column where every entry in the new column will be a portion of a percentage  total from a group they belong to.

Before:
[image]

```
for i in range(len(df7)):
    df7['perc'] = (df7[df7.loc[:, 'group'] == df7['group'][i]]['test']) / (df7[df7.loc[:, 'group'] == df7['group'][i]].test.sum())
    print(df7['perc'][i])
```

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and divide column:

```
df7['perc'] = df7['test'].div(df7['group'].map(df7['group'].value_counts()))
```

Alternative:

```
df7['perc'] = df7['test'].div(df7.groupby('group')['group'].transform('size'))
```